# Rally sdk Upcoming Releases / Sprints / Sprint Summary Apps

Tags: sdk, rally

I am using the Rally SDK with login key to create report pages.  I have mocked up report pages inside of Rally, but I cant seem to find these same apps exposed via the rally sdk.  I cant seem to locate any documentation for them, such as the Upcoming Releases app, Sprints app, or Sprint Summary app.  Are these available via the Rally SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reports that can be viewed outside of Rally using AppSDK 1.33 and below are listed [here](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/standard-reports).

Your Rally data can be exposed  via AppSDK 1.3x by writing custom apps, which is not the same as custom reports generated from Reports tab. Please follow these links on [writing apps](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/app-sdk) and [running apps outside of Rally](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps-outside-rally).

LoginKey functionality allows to display a Rally custom app or a Rally standard report without being prompted to login to Rally because a read-only user's credentials are encoded in the app's code. LoginKey documentation is available [here](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/loginkey).
LoginKey works with AppSDK 1.3x. It was not designed to work with [AppSDK 2](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/).

Comment: I already have the loginkey feature working, was hoping that there was some easy reporting app that I was missing for the three apps that I mentioned.  Bummer.

Comment: If you wrote a custom HTML/javascript code that runs inside Rally this custom app should work outside of Rally, as long as you use a fully qualified URL to SDK:

<script src="https://[server]/apps/[version]/sdk.js"></script>

and replaced the "hangman" variables (__WORKSPACE_OID__,  ___PROJECT_OID__, ...) with respective OIDs